# how to render a HTML template on button click in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Scenario: on button click event i will trigger a function wherein that function it will generate a html template and i will need to append dynamic values on the body of the generated template and open it in a pop-up.

the code is some like this

```
buttonClick() {
data: any;

window.open(
`
<html>
   <head><title>${data.title}</title></head>
   <body>${data.contents}</body>
</html>
`,  '_blank'
)
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I know you solve your question, but... What about use a pop-up in Angular (there're several in libraries like ng-bootstrap or material-angular, or even you can create one using cdk)? it's a bit "bizarro" use Javascript to do it.